# Gaps between CardView is too large

Tags: android, cardview

I use CardView. But gaps between cards is large. Gap equals one screen.
What did I do wrong? Before scrolling cards view like good. After scrolling gap between cards increases.

content_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/program_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

program_item.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:contentPadding="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="false"
    card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/programName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

[before scrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/msEd3.png)
[after scrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6cPY.png)

Comment: Add `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` to  `LinearLayout` inside `CardView`.

Comment: @ADM Thak you. I changed layout_height and problem resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your linear layout wrap_content inside the cardview. It is taking up all the height

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
card_view:contentPadding="10dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="false"
card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/programName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />
</LinearLayout>
```